# Override a td tag style from an outside source

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Good day... yes I am a nOOb. So I apologize for my nOObness right off the top. I have searched this site and many like it for a week without any resolution. I believe my problem is unique.

I have a site with about 10 pages that I am creating that have lots and lots of tables on them. Most of the tables are formatted the same way so I immediately went to CSS for my needs.

So now I am trying to understand CSS and selectors and how to combine them etc.

Here is my dilemma. I have created a tag style for the `<td>` tag which works great on about 95% of everything I am doing. I have also created an "override" class for it for those instances when I want to align left and indent the `<td>`:

```
TD {                
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            all other rules;}

td.overide_l {
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-left: 1em;
            all other rules;}
```

My problem comes from a piece of corporate controlled javascript that creates a lefthand nav menu. Apparently, there are td's in that code that is affected by my rule. The problem is that the javascript is not something that I can make changes to. It is a corporate script saved on a corporate site, yet needs to be on each of my pages.

If I change the `<td>` style to left align the script will align to the left. If I remove the `<td>` tag all together it will align to the left. If I make the `<td>` style center aligned like I want it, the script center aligns the left nav and I can't override it.

I have tried a thousand things. I tried to put the script in a separate table with the class override in it, I tried placing it in a separate td that surrounded it, I have put the class="overide_l" class in a `<span>`.

Lastly, I tried creating `<div>`'s that had id's associated with them which worked, but then my Class="overide_l" (and a plethora of other class styles I had created), didn't work within the new divs anymore...

```
div#content-section td {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;}
```

Ultimately what I want to do is leave the tag style like it is at the top of this post and simply create a `<div>` or something that will shut off the `<td>` tag style for that one piece of code. Is this even possible?

Can you please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do the same thing you did with your `td` selector with your override class?

```
#content-section td.overide_l {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

The problem is specificity:

- 100 points for an ID selector
- 10 points for a class selector
- 1 for a tag selector

If you add up the selectors, you get the selector that will take precedence.

In your case:

`td.overide_l` = `11`

`div#content-section td` = `102`

So the second wins.  Changing `td.overide_l` to `#content-section td.overide_l` will make it `111`.

Comment: So what will this do? This will make my overide work within the new divs I created?

Comment: @DuncanColby I don't understand what you mean.  Making that change will make the override work with a `div` with that ID.  It would probably be better for you to create a `class` instead of an `id` so you can apply it to more than one element on your page.

Comment: So if I create a class like div.normal td{ and an overide div.normal td.overide_l{ I could use them in as many different divs as I need? Then I would need to do something like: `<div class="normal">` `<table>` `<tr>` `<td class="overide_l">`

Comment: Yes, and btw you could just put `.normal` there is no need for the `div` unless you must limit it to `div`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is be more specific in your css rules. Putting a rule on all elements (td) is a bad idea for exactly the reason you are illustrating here. Have the tables in your code have a different class so that your CSS rules know the difference between those and the nav tds. Also, if you guys are using tables for so much, you guys are going to have a bad time.

Comment: That's just it I was trying to avoid having to put a class selector on every td in the site...

Comment: That is why you are going to have a bad time with tables.